# How to run {gunicorn | or any python program} as python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn, python-2.x

When I run gunicorn, python2 is always executed.

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app

...

ps -ef | grep gunicorn

user    34877      1  0 16:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app
user    34883  34877  0 16:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app
user    34884  34877  0 16:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app
...
```

(If you want to check my environment, follow this repo : https://github.com/be-hase/ghe-line-notify)

How can I run gunicorn as python 3?

I think it's an error caused by running gunicorn as python2.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 379: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

It took too much time, but it was too simple.
I can check where the gunicorn is with the following command. (Already installed python3)

```
$ whereis gunicorn
gunicorn: /usr/bin/gunicorn /usr/local/bin/gunicorn
```

and then, I check two file.

```
$ vim /usr/local/bin/gunicorn
    
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    ...
    ...
```

(I think I found the Python 3 version!)

and then, I run like this.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app
```

and then, I can see

```
user    39677  39672  3 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app
user    39678  39672  3 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app
...
```

---

Additionaly I changed Python's alias to Python 3 path and tried it, but it didn't solve it, but I don't know why.